# What type of structure is this data?

Tags: html, mysql, wordpress, forms

I have this mysql table with a field with this value:

```
a:18:{
i:0;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:10;
        i:1;
        s:5:"Email";
        i:2;
        s:10:"user_email";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"y";
        i:5;
        s:1:"y";
        i:6;
        s:1:"y";
    }
i:1;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:1;
        i:1;
        s:10:"First Name";
        i:2;
        s:10:"first_name";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"y";
        i:5;
        s:1:"y";
        i:6;
        s:1:"y";
    }
i:2;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:2;
        i:1;
        s:9:"Last Name";
        i:2;
        s:9:"last_name";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"y";
        i:5;
        s:1:"y";
        i:6;
        s:1:"y";
    }
i:3;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:4;
        i:1;
        s:9:"Address 2";
        i:2;
        s:5:"addr2";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:4;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:5;
        i:1;
        s:4:"City";
        i:2;
        s:4:"city";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:5;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:6;
        i:1;
        s:5:"State";
        i:2;
        s:8:"thestate";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:6;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:7;
        i:1;
        s:3:"Zip";
        i:2;
        s:3:"zip";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:7;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:9;
        i:1;
        s:9:"Day Phone";
        i:2;
        s:6:"phone1";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"y";
        i:5;
        s:1:"y";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:8;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:9;
        i:1;
        s:9:"Alt Phone";
        i:2;
        s:6:"phone2";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"y";
        i:5;
        s:1:"y";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:9;
a:9:{
        i:0;
        i:9;
        i:1;
        s:9:"GENDER";
        i:2;
        s:6:"gender";
        i:3;
        s:4:"select";
        i:4;
        s:1:"y";
        i:5;
        s:1:"y";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
        i:7;
        s:4:"male";
        i:8;
        s:5:"female";
    }
i:10;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:11;
        i:1;
        s:13:"Confirm Email";
        i:2;
        s:13:"confirm_email";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:11;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:3;
        i:1;
        s:9:"Address 1";
        i:2;
        s:5:"addr1";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:12;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:8;
        i:1;
        s:7:"Country";
        i:2;
        s:7:"country";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:13;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:14;
        i:1;
        s:8:"Password";
        i:2;
        s:8:"password";
        i:3;
        s:8:"password";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:14;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:15;
        i:1;
        s:16:"Confirm Password";
        i:2;
        s:16:"confirm_password";
        i:3;
        s:8:"password";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:15;
a:9:{
        i:0;
        i:16;
        i:1;
        s:3:"TOS";
        i:2;
        s:3:"tos";
        i:3;
        s:8:"checkbox";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"n";
        i:7;
        s:5:"agree";
        i:8;
        s:1:"n";
    }
i:16;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:12;
        i:1;
        s:7:"Website";
        i:2;
        s:8:"user_url";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"y";
    }
i:17;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:13;
        i:1;
        s:17:"Biographical Info";
        i:2;
        s:11:"description";
        i:3;
        s:8:"textarea";
        i:4;
        s:1:"n";
        i:5;
        s:1:"n";
        i:6;
        s:1:"y";
    }
}
```

I've seen this multiple times before in other databases, but I'm not sure what type of data type/field this is?  Reason I ask because I'm trying to get make element in there for input type "select" but can't seem to figure it out.  Anyone know?

From my understanding, the above data is serialization of form input elements, like text box, check box, etc.

So how would they serialize a select input box? For example:

```
<select>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `serialized` data, most likely by the php function `serialize()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

> Description:
>
> string serialize ( mixed $value ) Generates a storable representation
>   of a value.
>
> This is useful for storing or passing PHP values around without losing
>   their type and structure.
>
> To make the serialized string into a PHP value again, use
>   unserialize().

Example:

```
<?php
  $obj = new stdclass;
  $obj->prop1 = 1;
  $obj->prop2 = "two";
  $arr = array(0, 1, 2, array("key" => "value", "another key" => "another value"), $obj);
  print serialize($arr);
?>
```

will output:
`a:5:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;a:2:{s:3:"key";s:5:"value";s:11:"another key";s:13:"another value";}i:4;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"prop1";i:1;s:5:"prop2";s:3:"two";}}`

And to explain a snippet of yours, take:

```
a:18:{
i:0;
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:10;
        i:1;
        s:5:"Email";
        i:2;
        s:10:"user_email";
        i:3;
        s:4:"text";
        i:4;
        s:1:"y";
        i:5;
        s:1:"y";
        i:6;
        s:1:"y";
    }
```

It's saying the data is an array with 18 elements `a:18`, the element at index 0 `i:0` is an array of 7 elements `a:7`, the element at index 0 of that array `i:0` is an integer with the value 10 `i:10`, the element at index 1 `i:1` is a string of length 5 `s:5` with the value `email`. and so on.

a `var_dump` of just the first element from your serialized data gives:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    int(10)
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Email"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "user_email"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "text"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "y"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "y"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "y"
  }
}
```

To serialize your particular snippet - well, there's a few ways to do it and i don't have a wordpress handy to verify it, but one way would simply be to represent it in php like this:

```
$input = array('type' => 'select');
$opts = array(array('value' => 1, 'text' => '1'), array('value' => 2, 'text' => '2'));
$input['options'] = $opts;
$serialized = serialize($input);
```

which would give you a string that looks like 
`a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"select";s:7:"options";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"value";i:1;s:4:"text";s:1:"1";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"value";i:2;s:4:"text";s:1:"2";}}}`

Comment: great thanks man.  Now you know how they formatted a select input type for that data above?  basically you know the structure for it?

Comment: Note that if the data is not stored properly after doing serialization then on using `unserialize` you might get errors like `Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 788 bytes` the message may be different in different cases.

Comment: so how would they serialize a select input box?  for example:  <input type="select"><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select>

Comment: that would depend on how they store the data for the select box.eg if they are storing the text, and value for each option, it may be stored like this `a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"value";i:1;s:4:"text";s:8:"option 1";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"value";i:2;s:4:"text";s:8:"option 2";}}`, which would be deserialized and then looped over to construct the `option` tags

Comment: hmm i c...because for a check box they did not use an inner array for the check box values...so im trying to see if they followed that same convention for select type..

Comment: re @AbhikChakraborty comment - the most common error is when the data is copy pasted and the whitespace isn't removed.